# How to update RefersToR1C1 Excel named range in Visual Studio/VB

Tags: excel, vb.net

Latest edit: I've tried a ton of stuff, still can't figure this out. A more concise question is how I assign the variable. Per the first comment I got, I'm using VSTO.

```
    Dim wksSheetVSTO As Worksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(wsThisSheet)
    Dim nrThisNamedRange As NamedRange = ???
```

Original Question:

I am brand new to Visual Studio/VB.Net but am an experienced VBA programmer. I have a very complex spreadsheet that uses Excel named ranges, and I can’t seem to figure out how I can manipulate them.

The existing spreadsheet uses Excel named ranges that essentially act like database tables. When a user adds a row, it adds a row to the named range. Since Excel doesn’t automatically extend the range itself, the VBA code re-defines the named range to include the new row by re-defining the RefersToR1C1 property of the named range. It works perfectly in VBA. (I can post the working VBA code if it helps.)

In Visual Studio/VB, I can’t figure out a way to assign a variable to the named range. The only documentation I can find talks about assigning a variable by creating a NEW named range, but I already have the named range. My work-around (which works, but looks bad to me) is below:

```
   Dim rngDataStore As Excel.Range
   Dim nrThisNamedRange As NamedRange

   ...<<stuff happening here>>...

    rngDataStore.Resize(1).Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown)

    ' The next line is what I don't want.
    nrThisNamedRange = wksSheetVSTO.Controls.AddNamedRange(wksSheetVSTO.Range("A1"), <<name>>)
    nrThisNamedRange.RefersToR1C1 = <<new named range R1C1 here>>
```

I don’t want to just extend the working range (rngDataStore), I need to actually update the definition of the named range so that I can continue to reference and write to it. (This is doing what ctrl+F3 allows you to do within Excel.) I’ve tried looping through the Names collection, but other than using the ‘Controls.AddNamedRange’ I can’t figure out how to simply assign the nrThisNamedRange variable and update its RefersToR1C1 property.

Added: The above code doesn't always work, it's giving me an error that the named range already exists. (Which of course I know!)

Comment: I do not use VSTO,hence I am not familiar with the NamedRange control.  However, the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.referstor1c1.aspx) for it indicate that you assign the range formula to the RefersToR1C1 property just like you would to the Excel.Name object.  Is your problem that `rngDataStore.Address(True, True, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, False, False)` is not returning what you have assumed to be a resized range?  `Range.Resize` is a property, you need to assign its result. `rngDataStore=rngDataStore.Resize(rows,cols)`

Comment: Thanks TnTinMn, I used the doc you linked to in order to get my code above to work like in the above sample. My problem isn't with manipulating the range itself (referred to as rngDataStore above) -- that all works fine. But what I need to do is re-assign the underlying/original Excel named range, and basically all I'm asking is how to assign the variable nrThisNamedRange without using the 'AddNamedRange' action.

Comment: Have you seen the example on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.formular1c1.aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: Thanks Slai, yes I saw that article. It adds a new named range. (All the examples I've found add a new named range. None of them try to manipulate an existing named range.) I don't want to add one, I already have them in the worksheet and need to reference them, that's all.

Comment: Pretty much the same as in VBA: `rngDataStore.Worksheet.Names["name"].RefersToR1C1 = "=R1C1";`. I am not sure if you can get a `NamedRange` object without adding it, as there doesn't seem to be [`GetVstoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.applicationfactory.getvstoobject.aspx) method for it

Comment: maybe Excel tables (`ListObject`) can be used instead as those auto-resize when data is entered right below them, and are easier to access/manipulate/databind with [`GetVstoObject(ListObject)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee248048.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Slai but that suggestion didn't work. I also tried `wsThisSheet.Names.Item("name").RefersToR1C1 = "=R1C1"` but that too doesn't work. I might have to look at using ListObjects but what a pain that will be -- this spreadsheet uses about 100 named ranges, many of which are sandwiched one after the other so I'd have to basically re-engineer the whole thing. It just seems crazy to me that I can't access the Named Range...especially since this works perfectly in VBA.

Comment: seems a bit unusual for something that works in VBA to not work in `Interop.Excel` (not `Tools.Excel`). You can add the VBA code to your question just in case. Global named ranges are in the `Workbook.Names` instead of the `Worksheet.Names`

Comment: Wow @Slai you did it. Do you want to answer it so that I can upvote it? Turns out that the Named Ranges I was referencing were indeed Global (i.e. at the workbook level) and this worked like a charm: `Globals.ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("name").RefersToR1C1 = "=R1C1" ` Now I'll just have to overload the function for global vs. worksheet named ranges. THANKS TO YOU!

Comment: I assumed you would know that because of the "am an experienced VBA programmer" :] The `.Item` part is optional, and I just realized that I was giving C# code samples in a VB.Net question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For global named range:

```
Dim name = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("name")
Dim range = name.RefersToRange
name.RefersTo = range.Resize(range.Rows.Count + 1)
```

Comment: FYI when I use just `.Names("name")` I get an error that it is expecting an integer. That's why I was using `.Names.Item("name")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

@Slai helped me uncover the answer (the worksheet had global named ranges in it) so I thought I'd at least share the full function for anyone who might need it.

```
  Function ExpandNamedRange(sRangeName As String, lRowsToAdd As Long, sSheetName As String) As Boolean
    ' Adds the specified number of rows and resets the surrounding named range.

    Dim wsThisSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Worksheets(sSheetName)
    Dim rngDataStore As Excel.Range = wsThisSheet.Range(sRangeName)

    If lRowsToAdd > 0 Then
        rngDataStore.Resize(lRowsToAdd).Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown)

        ' For a global/workbook named range
        Globals.ThisWorkbook.Names.Item(sRangeName).RefersToR1C1 = "=" & wsThisSheet.Name &
                               "!R" & rngDataStore.Row - lRowsToAdd & "C" & rngDataStore.Column &
                               ":R" & rngDataStore.Row + rngDataStore.Rows.Count - 1 & "C" & rngDataStore.Column + rngDataStore.Columns.Count - 1

        ' For a local/worksheet named range
        'wsThisSheet.Names.Item(sRangeName).RefersToR1C1 = "=" & wsThisSheet.Name &
        '                       "!R" & rngDataStore.Row - lRowsToAdd & "C" & rngDataStore.Column &
        '                       ":R" & rngDataStore.Row + rngDataStore.Rows.Count - 1 & "C" & rngDataStore.Column + rngDataStore.Columns.Count - 1
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Two things I learned:
(1) I didn't actually have to refer to a NamedRange object at all, I could just use the Names collection of the workbook; I was originally trying that because my first attempts failed. But this is nice, it saved me steps.
(2) In VBA, you can refer to 'global' Named Ranges from anywhere. That's where I got stuck.